# Drupal Dynamic Side Bar

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-theming

how to add a dynamic sidebar on drupal? 
(Like how do we create a sidebar with the top 3 videos)

Comment: I want to add a side bar with top 3 videos and top 3 news. How can I do that? (create a new content type or use views)

Comment: Once again, what have you already tried? Did you experience any *specific* problems with your attempts?

Comment: No I haven't any experience. I have no idea to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Block View and filter it by your video content type. Limit it to 3. Then on the blocks configuration page, drag your newly created block into the sidebar of your choice.
You can do the same for your news content type. Just create another block view that's filtered by your news content type.